# How to push the ids of selected option of dropdowns into an array using jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hi I am new to jquery actually I had an dropdown in my html where I will get the options from database using ajax here I am retrieving the id and option from database but showing only the options in the dropdown

The code for dropdown which I done so far in html is

```
<div id="container" class=""></div>
<button id="seedoc" style="float: right; margin-right: 10px;" onclick="addOne();"></button>
function addOne() {
getEmails();
$('#container').append(
<div class='form-group' style='display:flex'>
<select class='drop form-control'  name='option' id='option'>
<option value='' disabled selected>Select your option</option>
</select>
                <button class="btn btn-primary shrBtn" style="float:left;" onclick="send()">Send</button>

</div>
```

the json response I get from db.php is

```
users:
[ "<p style='margin:0px;display:none;'data-id='755'>amilham</p>",
"<p style='margin:0px;display:none;'data-id='706'>a_sarabi</p>"]
```

and in dropdown I am getting amilham,a_sarabi so here in the dropdown if I select amilham I need to get the data-id i.e 755 into an array and also in the another dropdown if I select a_sarabi I need to get 706 into array using jquery

can anyone help me please

so far I tried like this but not getting

```
function send()
{
    var uids = [];
    \$('.drop').change(function(){
   \$(this).find('option:selected').each(function(){
       uids.push(\$(this).attr('data-id') );
    });
   });
```

I need all the ids of selected options in all the dropdowns I add using jquery
Populating options from db into dropdown

```
function getEmails(){
        
    
    \$.ajax({
        url :'propage.php',
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'json',
        data : '&userId='+\$('#hdn_userid').val()+'&action=getEmails',
        success : function(res){
            res.users.forEach(function(option) {
            \$('.drop').append('<option>' + option + '</option>');
        });
      },
    });
  }
```

Comment: can you show code for populating options inside dropdown ?

Comment: @Swati yes please once see I had written the ajax code please help me

Comment: @swith You are mixing up things. You do not have any `data-id` in the options you are appending and you are expecting for options to have `data-id` in your `send` function ? The response from `db.php` includes a `p` with `data-id` you code needs alot of fixing.

Comment: but in the json response I am having data-id but I dont want to show it on front end but need the selected option data-ids in an array can you say how can I achieve it please
@AlwaysHelping

Comment: @swith You are not appending / adding any `data-id` here `$('.drop').append('<option>' + option + '</option>');`

Comment: so can you say how to add it in hidden mode @AlwaysHelping help me!

Comment: @swith See my answer below. i really hope that's what you wanted. Let me know.

Comment: @swith many people are there to help you.. don't ignore them or there answers.

Comment: @ Swati I am sorry I didnt seen yours as @AlwaysHelping kept the answer first I dont say your answer is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a demo example *(by adding your `json` response data form db.php)* of what you are saying. You can store the `data-id` on clicking send button.

Run snippet below and select the option and click send to see the array `uids` will have the `data-id` of the selected option.

```js
//Store in array()
var uids = [];

   //Select option function
$(document).on("change", ".drop", function() {

  //Find option selected
  var data = $(this).find("option:selected").attr('data-id')

  //Push selected data-id
  uids.push(data)

  //Enable button on selection
  $('#seedoc').prop('disabled', false)


})

//Send
function send() {
  console.log(uids)
}

//response
var res = {
  "users": ["<p style='margin:0px;display:none;'data-id='755'>amilham</p>",
    "<p style='margin:0px;display:none;'data-id='706'>a_sarabi</p>"
  ]
}


function getEmails() {
  res.users.forEach(function(option) {
    $('.drop').append('<option data-id=' + $(option).attr('data-id') + '>' + option + '</option>');
  });
}

function addOne() {

  $('#container').append("<div class='form-group' style='display:flex'><select class='drop form-control' name='option' id='option'> <option value='' disabled selected>Select your option</option> </select>");
  getEmails();

}
getEmails();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" class=""></div>
<button id="seedoc" style="float: right; margin-right: 10px;" onclick="addOne();" disabled>Add one </button>

<div class='form-group' style='display:flex'>
  <select class='drop form-control' name='option' id='option'>
    <option value='' disabled selected>Select your option</option>

  </select>
  <button class="btn btn-primary shrBtn" style="float:left;" onclick="send()">Send</button>

</div>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218861/discussion-on-answer-by-alwayshelping-how-to-push-the-ids-of-selected-option-of).